# Java Inflate inconsistent with large Strings

Tags: java, compression, inflate, deflate

I want to recover a compressed medium length string (665 chars) using `java.util.zip` package, The compression is made by this code:

```
public String compress(String s){
    Deflater def = new Deflater(9);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[s.length()];
    String rta = "";
    def.setInput(s.getBytes());
    def.finish();
    def.deflate(buffer);
    rta = new String(buffer);
    rta = rta.trim().concat("*" + Integer.toString(s.length()));
  //this addition at the end is used to recover the original length of the string to dynamically create the buffer later on.
    return rta;
}
```

And the code to decompress is this:

```
public String decompress(String s){
    String rta = "";
    Inflater inf = new Inflater();
    byte[] buffer = separoArray(s, true).getBytes(); // This function returns the compressed string or the original length wheter true/false parameter
    int len = Integer.valueOf(separoArray(s, false));
    byte[] decomp = new byte[len];
    inf.setInput(buffer);
    try {
        inf.inflate(decomp, 0, len);
        inf.end();
    } catch (DataFormatException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    rta = new String(decomp);
    return rta;
}
```

And this are the original String and the decompressed one:

Original:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed rutrum imperdiet consequat. Nulla eu sapien tincidunt, pellentesque ipsum in, luctus eros. Nullam tristique arcu lorem, at fringilla lectus tincidunt sit amet. Ut tortor dui, cursus at erat non, interdum imperdiet odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla facilisi. Duis eget auctor nibh. Cras ante odio, dignissim et sem id, ultrices imperdiet erat. Aenean ut purus hendrerit, bibendum massa non, accumsan orci. Morbi quis leo sed mauris scelerisque vulputate. Fusce gravida facilisis ipsum pellentesque euismod. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae"

Decompressed:

"Lorem ipsuAdolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed rutrsuAimperdiet consequat. Nulla eu sapien tincidunt, pellentesquem ipsuAin, luctus eros. Nullam tristiquemarcu lLore, at fringilla lectus tincidunt sit amet. Ut tortor dui, cursus at erat non, interdsuAimperdiet odsAimpeIn hac habitasse platea dius ms Nulla eufacilisi. Duierog odatus dunibh. Craat erddsAim, dignissim  odsm ipd, ulistcesmperdiet odat n. Aenean ut pur athendreri pebibendAimmassaon, inacc msan orci. Morbi quierleodsmdmmausti sceleriuem ivulputate. Fusce gravideufacilisisipsuAinllentesquem ieuiemod. VeiqubulAin erddpsuAinlrimisipnufaucubus orciuctus erot ulistcesmposuereursbilia Cura"

The differences are visible, why is this happening?, what could I do to avoid it?

Thank You.

Comment: You're storing compressed (thus presumably binary) data as strings? That sounds like it'd open up for a whole bunch of potential problems, such as encoding and line endings messing stuff up.

Comment: Can you show the `separoArray` method?

Comment: You are mixing text and binary without considering the encoding used.  When you turn a byte[] into a String, the encoding is used to decode the byte[] and not all bytes are valid and thus it gets mangled.

Comment: BTW You would have about half the memory by just using a byte[] instead of a String.  Using a String to wrap it appears to defeat the purpose.

Comment: @assylias The compressed string is destined to be on a QR code, thus the compression and it has to be a String. If I add the "UTF-8" encoding to the String generation would be better?. The separoArray method does nothing but take the last chars indicating the length of the decompressed string from the compressed string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the commenters, that a compressed string should better be `byte[]`.
However with a single-byte encoding like ISO-8859-1 one might abusively convert between `byte[]` and `String`.

The following differs from your version, in that it explicitly indicates the encoding. For text UTF-8 is adequate to have no limits and cover the full Unicode range.

Note the usage of the `deflate` return value.

```
public static String compress(String s) {
    Deflater def = new Deflater(9);
    byte[] sbytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    def.setInput(sbytes);
    def.finish();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sbytes.length];
    int n = def.deflate(buffer);
    return new String(buffer, 0, n, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
            + "*" + sbytes.length;
}

public static String decompress(String s) {
    int pos = s.lastIndexOf('*');
    int len = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(pos + 1));
    s = s.substring(0, pos);
    
    Inflater inf = new Inflater();
    byte[] buffer = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    byte[] decomp = new byte[len];
    inf.setInput(buffer);
    try {
        inf.inflate(decomp, 0, len);
        inf.end();
    } catch (DataFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    return new String(decomp, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is *not* with `Deflater`.

The primary problem is this line:

```
    rta = new String(buffer);
```

What you are doing is taking an array of bytes (representing the compressed input string) and *decoding* it into a String using your platform's default character encoding.  This is wrong.  For the majority of character encodings, there are byte values of sequences of byte values that cannot be mapped to characters.  When you attempt to "decode" bytes that don't represent properly encoded text, you are liable to get a scattering of question marks or some other character throughout the string.  This results in loss of information ... and there's no way to recover it.

(There are one or two character sets where the decoding / encoding is fully reversible ... and you could use one of them as the encoding scheme when converting the compressed bytes to "text".  But that's not the end of it!)

The second problem with how you are dealing with the compressed bytes.  The `deflate(byte[] buffer)` method compresses the input data and writes the compressed output into `buffer`.  However, there is no guarantee that N bytes of input is going to result in N bytes of output.  Instead the `deflate` method returns an `int` giving the number of bytes written into `buffer`.

But your code is then taking the entire `buffer` ... including the bytes that *weren't* written ... and turning that into a String (by the unsound procedure described above).  You then `trim` the String to (I presume) get rid of the trailing NUL characters.  But that will trim *all* white-space from the start and end, and some of those characters could be a significant part of the compressed string.

---

Basically, what you are doing is *unsound*.  You should not be trying to convert arbitrary bytes into a String.  Compressed data is NOT text.

My recommendation is to do one of the following:

- Don't convert the (compressed) `byte[]` to a `String`.  Keep it as a `byte[]` ... and deal with the length issue properly.
- Alternatively, use a non-lossy bytes-as-characters encoding scheme; e.g. hex encoding or base64 encoding.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I never said the problem was the Deflater class, I just used that title to clarify my current predicament (ho ho.. what a phrase). The string is intended to be in a QR code, I'm using the zxing library and only accepts to generate the Image a string so, it has to be a string. I used the recommendation published by Joop Eggen and it worked, thank you anyways.

Comment: Your trim() suggestion healed my headache. Thanks also Saliba!! kkk